# Accessing Variable for use in ascx in Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a simple .ascx page that looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ctl_dataLookup.ascx.cs" Inherits="ctl_dataLookup" %>

<div>
    <h1>Data Lookup</h1>

    <p><%= d1 %></p>
</div>
```

The code behind page looks like this, and DoDataLookup method is called at the start of running this page:

```
public partial class ctl_dataLookup : BaseDomainControl
{

        private string d1;
        public string D1 { get { return d1; } }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            this.DataBind();
        }

        public void DoDataLookup(int DomainId, string DomainName)
        {
            this.Visible = true;

            d1 = "TEST DOMAIN";
        }


}
```

However, the <%= d1 %> always ends up looking like this when the page is rendered (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label):

[image]

I've looked at countless examples of this on Stack Overflow, but it looks as though I'm doing everything right... Is there any obvious reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using D1, not the private d1 variable.
Hope this works.

Thanks